# mongoose find query and function relationship

Tags: mongoose, count, find

I have the following beginner problem:
I would like return outside my query the number of documents retrieved with a find function. How to do ?

```
function citiesCounter (id) {
        City.find({ country: id })
        .then(cities_list => {
            //console.log(id + ' : ' + cities_list.length);
            return cities_list.length;
        });
};
```

doesn't return anything outside the then ! (City is a valid model)

thanks a lot

Comment: Call this function outside to get returned value:
var id = 1;
var counter = citiesCounter(id);

:)

Comment: Sure ! but the problem is that citiesCounter returns always undefined as I am not able to capture the return cities_list.length outside the City.find.

Comment: Please show your City model. Or try
     var citiesCounter = City.where({ country: id }).count();

[link to docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)

Comment: my schemas are var CountrySchema = Schema(
    {
        name_fr: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        name_en: { type: String, max: 100 }
    }
);
CountrySchema
    .virtual('cityCount')
    .get(function () {
        var counter  = City.where({ country: this._id }).count(); ;
        console.log(this.name_fr + ' : ' + counter);
        return counter;
    });

Comment: and var CitySchema = Schema(
  {
    name_fr: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    name_en: { type: String, max: 100 },
    country: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'country'
    }
  }
);

Comment: This is already implemented in your code: City.where({ country:id }).count(); -> returns number of cities per country id.

Comment: I thought so ! but it returns object [Object] instead of a value... I miss Something in my code .... :-(

Comment: Well, check the country 'id' you're passing to 'find' statement, it's probably invalid. And add .catch() block to see any errors occuring.